# Mapping a list of lat, long points to x, y in java: is there a cleaner way to do this?

Tags: javascript, html, maps

I've written a function which creates a custom map by translating lat, long points to x, y on a map inside a div. The map itself is contained as the background of the div, and the points are SVG elements on top, which allows the points to be interactive but the map to be static.

The way that it works right now is that each element has an id, and cx and cy are input by the programmer as coordinates. In the  section of the document, there is an array that contains the id of each point. The program runs through the array using .forEach, grabs the cx and cy values, does some math, and then changes the cx and cy value to place the point correctly on the map (see code at the bottom of the document).

This works fine, but I'm wondering if there's a more 'graceful' way to do it. The code as is isn't very user-friendly, you have to go through and give each point an id and update the array every time you add a new point. I recognize that it's a kind of clunky system. Is there a way to do this by, for example, telling the script to run for each element with a specific class onload?

Code below:

```css
#window {
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5d/World_map_%28Miller_cylindrical_projection%2C_blank%29.svg/634px-World_map_%28Miller_cylindrical_projection%2C_blank%29.svg.png);
  display: block;
  filter: none;
  background-color: #E3F2FD;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="pagestyle.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="window">
    <svg id="pins" viewBox="0 0 637.5 336.4">
              
                <circle class="pin" id="md" cx="-76.609" cy="39.291" r=".25%" fill="#000"/>
                <circle class="pin" id="ma" cx="-72.609" cy="42.371" r=".25%" fill="#000"/>
                <circle class="pin" id="nd" cx="-97.032" cy="40.714" r=".25%" fill="#000"/>
                <circle class="pin" id="tx1" cx="-94.741" cy="47.924" r=".25%" fill="#000"/>
                <circle class="pin" id="tx2" cx="-97.149" cy="32.501" r=".25%" fill="#000"/>
        
                <text id="tooltip" x="0" y="0" visibility="hidden" fill="#000" stroke="#000" font-size="10" font-family="Arial">Tooltip</text>
              </svg>
  </div>
  <script>
    //mapping function
    var users = [md, ma, nd, tx1, tx2];
    users.forEach(function(element) {
      var lon = parseInt(element.getAttribute("cx"));
      var xValue = (637.5 * ((lon + 180) / 360))-14;
      element.setAttribute("cx", xValue);
      var lat = parseInt(element.getAttribute("cy"));
      var yValue = (474.691 * ((Math.abs((((5 / 4) *
        (Math.asinh(Math.tan(((4 * Math.PI) / 900) * lat)))) + 2.30342) - 4.60684)) / 4.60684)) ;
      element.setAttribute("cy", yValue);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Update: added a background url sourced online instead of locally on my laptop and changed the x and y shifts to match the new map

Comment: where are you setting ak, md ...?

Comment: dynamo- not sure what you mean. The lat, long points are set as the original location attributes of the svg elements. The JS grabs those values and reprocesses them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would modify your code as the follows if you want the circles redrawn on load

```
document.body.onload = function(){
  var users = document.getElementsByClassName('pin');

  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
       var element = users[i]
       var lon = parseInt(element.getAttribute("cx"));
       var xValue = (637.5 * ((lon + 180) / 360)) - 22;
       element.setAttribute("cx", xValue);
       var lat = parseInt(element.getAttribute("cy"));
       var yValue = (474.691 * ((Math.abs((((5/4) * (Math.asinh(Math.tan(((4*Math.PI)/900) * lat)))) + 2.30342) - 4.60684)) / 4.60684)) - 35;
       element.setAttribute("cy", yValue);
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what this improves? This still requires using an array to contain all the IDs, for example.as far as I can tell you just added an extra step, and I'm unclear on why.